# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getProperty' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, mootools

I didn't write this script, but I've cleaned it up according to JSHint. Both versions (the messy one and the new one) both show me this error.

Here's a publicly accessible version of it:
http://yourjavascript.com/6310515531/jd-gallery.js

and [here is the site](http://sshs63.com/)

I had nothing to do with this site or anything, but I was just told to try and find out why 'the slider wasn't working', and I'm not quite sure why I'm getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getProperty' of null

on line 187 of this.

**EDIT:**

http://sshs63.com/undefined 404 (Not Found) shows up after the site is loaded for a bit too, I think as the slider tries to slide, but this error is on another JS file. It shows up in the console though, not quite sure what to do about either error

Comment: Usually `Uncaught TypeError` errors when associated with jQuery are due to a jQuery conflict, $ jQuery alias issue, or backwards-compatibility issue.  Look into jQuery.migrate and consider loading older or newer versions of jQuery to see if that might help.

Comment: if you see null (vs undefined), it's usually the result of a DOM operation of some kind, since that's about the only place null appears...

Answer (score 2):

On line `187 of jd-gallery.js file`

```
image: el.getElement(options.imageSelector).getProperty('src'),
```

When `options.imageSelector`   is **img.full** it turns out , it could not find the element.

So you see the error as you are trying to apply a method on null.